# How can you draw a line graph with one line only (and get values back)

Tags: vb.net

How do you draw a line graph during runtime in VB.NET and only allow for one line?  By one line I mean each X value can only have one Y value.  On top of that, I want to be able to pull the corresponding X and Y values of that line when finished.  For example:

Start with a blank set of axes running from 0 to 100 in both X and Y directions.  You click and hold your mouse and draw your desired curve (left side in picture).  Now you want to make modifications to the 30 - 50 X-value range.  You click at x=30 and draw a valley that comes back up just over x=50 (right graph in picture).  On this second click where the modification was made, note how a second line isn't drawn, but overrides the Y-value from the first click and patches it into the original line.

Lastly, I need to be able to pull the data from the table after the line is drawn.  So I would be left with a list of X,Y coordinates that defines the line.

[image]

Comment: Google vb.net graphics methods. And DO NOT get the data from the graph. Modify the data from the mouse and draw the data.

Comment: What front end technology?  WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or other?

Comment: WinForms.  @Trevor, out of curiosity, how come you suggest using vb.net graphics vs. a chart object and trying to pull/modify data from that?

Comment: You want to do mousy draw things with it so using a Chart would get complicated. Either way you need to accumulate your data and either draw the curve from that or apply the data to the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling around, I came up with something that seems to work pretty well.

In your application, add a chart object and set the chart type to spline (Properties -> Series -> ChartType = Spline).  I manually set my x and y axis ranges from 0 to 100.

**Global vars**

The x and y arrays MUST be the same length and will store the x/y points that will be plotted in the chart.

```
Dim bIsDragging = False

Dim xTest() As Integer = {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100}
Dim yTest() As Integer = {50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50}
```

**Mouse Events**

The idea here is that after a mouse down event, it is considered a "dragging" motion until a mouse up event.  The bIsDragging flag tracks this state.  Also note that the "dragging" event is stopped if the mouse leaves the chart window.

```
 Private Sub Chart1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseDown
    bIsDragging = True
End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseUp
    bIsDragging = False
End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseLeave
    bIsDragging = False
End Sub
```

**Mouse Move Event**

This is where the bulk of the action happens.  See comments for details.

```
    Private Sub Chart1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseMove

    If bIsDragging Then

        ' The PixelPositionToValue() command expects a value within the chart area size.  When your
        ' mouse leaves the top edge for example, there is a brief second where the PixelPositionToValue()
        ' has a value outside of the chart area window and throws and exception.  This prevents that exception.
        If e.X < 5 Or e.X > Chart1.Size.Width - 5 Or e.Y < 5 Or e.Y > Chart1.Size.Height - 5 Then
            Return
        End If

        ' Gets chart value based on mouse position
        Dim xChartVal As Integer = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X)
        Dim yChartVal As Integer = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y)

        ' Allows some drawing control outside of the hard axes lines.  For example,
        ' if you are trying to draw a line across the y=0 line, it would be hard to
        ' hold the mouse exactly at y=0 and is much eaasier to go in a region below
        ' the x-axis to ensure it says at y=0.  Note that the 0 and 100 values below are hard
        ' coded based on my manual chart axes regions of 0 to 100.
        If xChartVal < 0 Then
            xChartVal = 0
        End If
        If xChartVal > 100 Then
            xChartVal = 100
        End If
        If yChartVal < 0 Then
            yChartVal = 0
        End If
        If yChartVal > 100 Then
            yChartVal = 100
        End If

        ' This relates your current mouse position to the nearest '5' x value in the
        ' global array and then modifies the y-index that matches this x-value.
        ' There's probably a better way to record these positions, but my application is
        ' a table output to an arduino where a massive table to go through would impact performance.
        ' Therefore, my x-axis resolution 5 for 0 to 100 to keep the number of points rather small.
        xChartVal = Math.Round(xChartVal / 5) * 5
        yTest(Array.IndexOf(xTest, xChartVal)) = yChartVal

        ' Updates chart
        Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(xTest, yTest)

    End If

End Sub
```